# How to send running process to background?

Tags: linux, background-process

Once in a while I will issue a command that takes longer than I had thought it would (archiving a directory or something).  How do I escape the process, send it to the background, and return to the prompt?  I think there's a keyboard shortcut, but I can't find it..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you're using BASH, just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, which will suspend the process, and then use the `bg` command to send it to the background. If you want more detail have a look at this [article on BASH job control](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html).

Comment: FYI, you can use `command &` - if need to run process with long duration in the background (for example, in GUI processes that waits until closed, you can initially run it with `&` ).

Comment: saw the solution on google results but just showing up to say thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+Z works but, is it possible to move the job to the background without suspending it ?